# How to measure extra calls to findViewByID - RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Let’s say that each item in your `RecyclerView` list contains four nested `View`s, and you don't cache these views in a `ViewHolder`. If eight items fit on screen, approximately, how many extra `findViewById()` calls will be made if you scroll through 30 items?

In addition to the eight items that fit on screen, assume that two extra items are needed for smooth scrolling.

I think the answer is 60.

Am I right?

Comment: I didn't got it, what is the confusion?

Comment: Sorry. The correct answer is 80 anyways. I was trying to calculate how many times the findViewById() method would be called after 30 scrolling through 30 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming scrolling through 30 items, each item is bound to data only once.

Each item has 4 views inside, that makes 4 calls per `bind`.

Total `findViewById()` calls will be

```
30 * 4 = 120.
```

No calls should be made for 2 views since they are not bound yet.

Your question

> how many extra findViewById() calls will be made

Given:

8 items are visible.
2 items are hidden.

Had you cached the views total calls would be:

```
(8 + 2) * 4 = 40.
```

The extra calls would be 120 - 40 = **80**.